# Does anyone know why my function is converted to type tuple when i call it in another function?

Tags: python, function, scipy

I have written the following function to calculate the probability of a single reaction in a system fires and output the probability of each reaction in the system firing as an array:

```
def propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate):
    propensity = np.zeros(len(LHS))
    for row in range(len(LHS)):
            a = stoch_rate[row]     
            for i in range(len(popul_num)):
                if (popul_num[i] >= LHS[row, i]):       
                    binom_rxn = binom(popul_num[i], LHS[row, i])
                    a = a*binom_rxn
                else:
                    a = 0
                    break
            propensity[row] = a     
    return propensity
```

The inputs for this function are 3 arrays `popul_num` has the discrete number of molecules of each reactant, `LHS` is a 2D array with the ratios between each reactant and `stoch_rate` is the rate of each reaction.

I now want to call the function with the scipy.misc.derivative method in a different function to calculate the partial derivative:

```
def time_step_calc(popul_num, state_change_array, a0):
    # equation 22:
    expctd_net_change = a0*state_change_array
    print("expected net change:\n", expctd_net_change)
    # equation 24 partial differentiation:
    for x in range(len(popul_num)):
        part_propensity_diff = derivative(func=propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate), x0=popul_num[x])    <-- Error here, propensity_calc is converted into a tuple object?
        print("partial diff:\n", type(part_propensity_diff))
        # popul_num = numpy.ndarray --> derivative function needs a float to work
    # equation 26:
    t_step = epsi*a0 / sum(expctd_net_change*part_propensity_diff)
    delta_t = optimize.fmin(t_step, 0.00012) # take the minimum value of the partial derivative
    print("calculated delta_t:\n", delta_t)
    return delta_t
```

But the but when I supply the function argument with the propensity_calc function, the line indicated throws the following error `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

I dont understand where the tuple is coming from or why propensity_calc is converted into it?

EDIT: heres the traceback

```
File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc\common.py", line 119, in derivative
val += weights[k]*func(x0+(k-ho)*dx,*args)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Any suggestions?
Cheers

Comment: Could you post more of the error?

Comment: You aren't passing `propensity_calc` as an argument; you are *calling* the function on 3 (undefined) arguments, then passing the result of that call as the argument.

Comment: How do I fix that sorry?

Comment: Mike, for a start by reading the docs for `derivative`, and make sure you understand the example.  Then play with some simple examples of your own.  You need a clear understanding of what is a function, and what is the result of calling one.  The distinction also matters when using `optimize.fmin`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
func=propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)
```

I do not believe you need the

```
func=
```

`propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)` calls propensity_calc

`func=propensity_calc(LHS, popul_num, stoch_rate)` defines a tuple, or immutable sequence of objects. Think of an array of objects you cannot change.

Here is more on tuples: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Comment: It isn't obvious that `propensity_calc(...)` returns a tuple; it looks like it returns an array.  But the OP doesn't give us enough inputs to bother running it.  In any case you are right that OP's use is passing an evaluated function to `derivative` rather than a function that is expects.